# align subcaption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I need help aligning the subcaptions of my figures. I want it to be vertically and horizontally aligned. Thank you in advance.

[image: how it looks]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}

    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}
    \begin{figure}[!h]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}
    \centering

    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:backbone}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{backbone2}}\hfil
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:lipassemble}}{\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{lipids}}\\
    \par\vspace{2em}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:micelle}}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth, height=0.2\columnwidth]{micelle}}\hfil
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:invmicelle}}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth, height=0.2\columnwidth]{inverted_micelle}}\hfil
    \caption{\textbf{(A)}-General chemical formula for lipid and superimposed ball-and-stick structure showing hydrophilic and hydrophobic regions, \textbf{(B)}-Breakdown of phospholipid structure that assembles into a lipid bilayer and liposome, respectively \cite{phospho}, \textbf{(C)}-structure of micelle, \textbf{(D)}-structure of inverse micelle \cite{Lasic1}}

    \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, for the horizontal alignment you can use a `tabular` with two `c` columns; the vertical alignment comes from `\subcaptionbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{floatrow}

    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}

    \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{position=b}
    \centering

    \begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:backbone}}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}} &
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:lipassemble}}{\includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth]{example-image-a}} \\[2em]
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:micelle}}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth, height=0.2\columnwidth]{example-image-b}} &
    \subcaptionbox{\label{fig:invmicelle}}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth, height=0.2\columnwidth]{example-image-c}}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\textbf{(A)}-General chemical formula for lipid and superimposed ball-and-stick structure showing hydrophilic and hydrophobic regions, \textbf{(B)}-Breakdown of phospholipid structure that assembles into a lipid bilayer and liposome, respectively \cite{phospho}, \textbf{(C)}-structure of micelle, \textbf{(D)}-structure of inverse micelle \cite{Lasic1}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, that's a neat trick, as you can tell from my coding, im quite new to latex. cheers!